# how to convert user input to independent dummy variables

Tags: python, pandas, prediction, dummy-variable

I have a dataset which looks like below

```
Plant   Brand   Volume
A         HL      12
B         AG      14
A         FP      50000
G         TT      08
```

For training a model I made them(Plant-Brand) with pd.get_dummies method
It expands as 186 columns like below;

```
Plant_A    Plant_B ...  Brand_HL    Brand_AG   ...
   1          0            1           0
   0          1            0           1
   1          0            0           0
   0          0            0           0
```

My model works well but I need to work this model with user input

User should give only plantID, Brand and Volume manually
I need to convert these values and write in the same format(186 columns) in order to predict independent value

```
y_pred = model.predict(X_user)
```

How can I convert 4 dimension to 186? is there any method to make this quickly?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: how you are performing one hot encoding? If you sklean Scale method you can decode with one hot encoded value simply.

Comment: @Mohamed Thasih ah I use pandas method -< pd.get_dummies(df_categorical)

Comment: I suggest you to read this <a href='https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html'>link</a>

Answer (score 0):

you could use :

```
np_array = np.asarray(df) # df is your pandas DataFrame

np_array.resize((new_num_rows, new_num_columns))
```

but you have to keep in mind that old_num_rows * old_num_columns should be equal with new_num_rows * new_num_columns